# C# comparies string[] and dictionary and write out differences

Tags: c#

Basically i'm trying to write out the difference between two text files (if this value does exist in both files file the value out to a new file.  This is what I have so far but i'm not sure how to write out the differences.

```
string[] coacsv = File.ReadAllLines(textBox2.Text);      
var collected = File.ReadAllLines(filepath + "\\fs.csv").ToDictionary(s => s.Split('|')[0]);
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(filepath + "mA.csv"))
            {
                foreach (string coa in coacsv)
                {
                    string[] splitcoa = coa.Split(',');
                    string correctcoa = splitcoa[1];
                    string collectLine;
```

//this is where i'm not sure how to write out the differences  any help is always welcomed

When comparing collected to string correctcoa i'm trying to write out correctcoa if it does not appear in collected

the following code does not work but is sort of what i want to accomplish

```
if (collection.Contains(correctcoa))
                    {

                    }
                    else
                    {

                        //success
                    }
```

throws error Error  2   Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary' to 'System.Linq.ParallelQuery'

File1:
apple
orange
pear

file2:
orange
pear

Output:
apple

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more as to what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: You could dig a bit into this MSDN Article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx (Get and Enumerable off an array with `.AsEnumerable<T>()`)

Comment: Can you provide specific examples of input file contents?

Answer (score 0):

Try a [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) rather than a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Without sample inputs and outputs, I can't really figure out what you're going for, but here's a shot.

```
var coacsv = File.ReadAllLines(textBox2.Text).Select(s => s.Split(',')[1]);      
var collected = File.ReadAllLines(filepath + "\\fs.csv").Select(s => s.Split('|')[0]);
var notInSecondFile = coacsv.Except(collected);
foreach(var s in notInSecondFile)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```